# Lost all the files in my git repo, reset didn't work. What happened?

Tags: git, github

### Foreword

I'm new to git and have been using it on a project for a couple of months and just decided to make it available on Github. I just discovered that my backup script was working almost correctly, so I have everything backed up but it's sloppy. Pheww... but a Plan B, I hope.

### Problem

I realized that some netCDF data files were basically being duplicated in the version control (= huge `.git` repository), so I was trying to exclude those by first adding these file extensions (and some test/data directories) to the `.gitignore` file in the root directory. This appears to only ignore version control of these files, but still includes them in the `.git` repository. I then added them to `.git/info/exclude`, which I believe ignores them entirely from the repository.

With each discovery, I first did a

```
git pull [my_repo] master
```

then a

```
git push [my_repo] master
```

After the second iteration (when I think I had only added things to .gitignore), I received an error stating that I had some issue with files needing to be merged. I had first created the `.gitignore` on gitHub, which was different, and I assumed this to be the problem and commenced merging.

On the third iteration (having added things to the `.git/info/exclude` file), everything went fine, but I saw that only the directories I wanted EXCLUDED were present on gitHub. Back on my disk, everything else was gone, including the netCDF data files...

I've tried `git reset --hard master`, and everything is the same when reset.

### Can anybody shed light on this?  Possible solutions?

I can't seem to find a similar problem; though, I imagine I can't be the first to have done this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: TL;DR version:

If you find a file in the repo that you want ignored by git:

1. remove it from only the git repository

   `git rm --cached filesToIgnore`
2. Put the file or a wildcard rule (ex. `*.swp`) inside the `.gitignore` file. Then save the repository with a `git commit`

Okay, I don't have it all pieced together entirely but lets break down what went wrong:

1st.  there is no difference between `.gitignore` and `.git/info/exclude` except that the former gets checked into the repository and is for project specific files to ignore while the later is for environment specific files such as `.swp` files pertaining to vim temp files.

With that in mind, putting the file into the `.git/info/exclude` file would only ignore new files, not files already apart of the repository (which I assume the netCDF files were)

2nd.  With the `git pull`, it first does a `git fetch` for the remote repository and then attempts to merge the remote and the local repository.  Why is this relevant?  Because if you have any local unchecked files, it will complain.  This is the error I'm guessin you saw.

3rd. Since you forced the merge, you probably ended up discarding any non checked in files.  These are gone.  Since they were never checked into git, git doesn't know about them.

EDIT:  However, as cHao pointed out, any previous files in git commits are still there.  Look through your repository with `git log` and temporarily checking out any of them with `git checkout <checksumNumber>`.  Use `git reset --hard <checksumNumber>` to permanently reset the repository to that commit.

4th.  What you need to do when you find files that are in your git repository that you want ignored the correct process is to

`git rm --cached filesToIgnore`

which will remove them from the git repo but not from the working directory.

Then add them to the .gitignore file, commit changes and you should be good to go.

Comment: The one thing I cannot explain is why you only saw the files excluded on github.  It should have been that you saw those file *and* any other files from previous commits.

Comment: This was very helpful. That all sounds about right. I am very curious to know why the excluded files were those that showed up as well.

Comment: WRT excluded files on github: It sounds like you had them in your repo, then ignored them, then accidentally removed all files from your repo. Since they were ignored, the removal action didn't affect them.

Comment: @codelark Crud-a-mundo. I think you're right. zanegray's 4th item is very helpful in this instance, and I think it should be put at the beginning of any discussion of `.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude`. So glad I had my backup running properly, or today would have been a massively bad day.

Comment: Backups are defiantly a good thing to have :)  And yes, item 4 is the gist of the correct way to go about it, but I was trying to break down what actually happened.  Maybe ill add a TLDR section.

Comment: Note, if you `git rm --cached`, and anyone else pulls, it'll delete those files in their copy.  For stuff like accidentally committed config files, that's a big deal.  :P  They'll have to `git rm --cached` and commit locally as well, so the histories of those files agree without the actual change being applied.

Answer (score 1):

First off...to get your stuff back.  `master` is now what you see in your working copy, deletions and all.  You'll need to either revert or reset, depending on whether you have other people pulling from this repo.  (If you don't, either will work.  Resetting gives you a cleaner change log, though.)

Note, the way i'm doing this is a bad idea if other people have pulled the bad merge from your repo.  But if you're the only one using it, or they haven't noticed yet...

- Delete or move the `exclude` file.  Something's obviously a bit wacky here, and the fewer variables you have to deal with, the better.
- `git log --summary`.  Look for the commit that removed the files.  I'm going to use `abcd1234` in this example.)
- `git reset --hard abcd1234~1` to go to the commit right before it.  (You don't have to put the whole SHA in; just enough to disambiguate.)

Your stuff should be back now.  If you're the only one using your repo, you can safely `git push --force origin master` to overwrite the old (invalid) head.

If other people have pulled from the repo, reverting the commit causes less of a problem.  You could get them to do the reset you just did, and that'd work...but if you don't know who's pulling, which is the default case on Github, then.  :P

To revert, instead of the `git reset` above, simply say `git revert abcd1234`.  That'll undo the changes from that commit.  If the files were somehow deleted over multiple commits, specify them all at once to revert everything with one commit.  Either way, you don't need the `--force` with the push anymore, since your local head is still a descendant of the origin's.

As for what caused all this...files already in the repo shouldn't just disappear, period.  `.gitignore` and `exclude` don't affect files already in the repo.  There's something wacky going on, and absent a full history, it'd be near impossible to piece together exactly what happened

Comment: This is also very helpful, and just reminded me I left out an important part of my story. I'd created my repository one directory higher than I decided I wanted it, and with putting it up on git, I decided I would delete it (and just lose my history, which I could live with) and init a new one. I can't really recollect what I did exactly there, but perhaps in this scenario only commits were performed on the files intended to be excluded.

Comment: @shootingstars: Yeah, that is a pretty important part.  :)  As you were commenting, i was editing to include a "yeah, this shouldn't happen...and without knowing what you did..."  lol

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion, is stop using git or github altogether and go back to using old fashioned folders, and save a copy of your folder in the cloud, and another copy on usb.

I understand that git is good for collaboration, but for simply easy personal projects, I think its an overkill. Also, I think the new kids are making things soo complicated. .NET CORE, MVVM, MVM, NPM, VUE, REACT, NODE.JS, arrow functions, ect...

I remember in the early 2000s, I was a Microsoft software engineer who went by the book and did all my coding according to Microsoft best practices and THEN, everything got complicated, Microsoft release new ways to do the same old stuff, such as LINQ to access data, when I used to use tried and tested Enterprise Data Access Application Block. Then they changed ASP.NET to something weird with Model View Controller crap instead of Web Forms. Then they even added other front-end frameworks. I understand change. I understand that IT is an ever changing landscape, but I am of the opinion that change for the sake of change is not a reason to change. By the way, did you know that you can still run a 30 year old UNIX command today on UNIX and it still WORKS! My question is this, how can large enterprises who have large heavily invested legacy applications ever get their head above water when 6 months later something "NEW" is released to do the same thing that the old legacy stuff does perfectly for 20 years. I think that IT is running around like chickens without heads, just consider that 40 year old legacy mainframes that receive input from terminals is analogous to the API calls that modern JavaScript applications use today. Also terminals 40 years ago had "single page applications", albiet not fancy but still they were ONE PAGE that "partially refreshed" based on the backend legacy application.

Just my comical yet true 2 cents